# Gstreamer tutorial gives distorted/warped video

Tags: c, ubuntu, gstreamer, ubuntu-18.04, gstreamer-1.0

I am running Ubuntu *(18.04.01 LTS)* on a virtual machine *(VMware Fusion 11.0.0)* and I want to go through the first basic GStreamer [tutorial](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/hello-world.html). This example should play a short video from the internet using the playbin element. However, when I compile and run the code, the resulting video is [distorted/warped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8R8t.png). When I download the file and play it directly from the desktop, everything looks fine. Same problem with other video files.

I have successfully followed the instructions how to install GStreamer *(gstreamer-1.0, version 1.14.1)* on Ubuntu and all the required additional plugins:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools
```

The same problem occurs when I play the video using `gst-launch-1.0` directly in the terminal:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm
```

Anybody has an idea what's going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a stride error. Probably due to a video driver issue between bridging the VM. Perhaps try a different non accelerated video renderer for your GStreamer ouput. Or disable VM's GPU hardware acceleration.

Comment: Thanks! The issue remains (slightly worse) when I disable the 3D graphics acceleration in the VM's settings. I am using a Macbook Pro with an integrated Intel Iris Pro and a dedicated NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M GPU.

Comment: Try `playbin video-sink=ximagesink uri=..`. Other renderers are `xvimagesink` or `glimagesink`. Hopefully one of these do the trick for you.

Comment: Awesome! `ximagesink` and `glimagesink` works perfectly fine, it's `xvimagesink` which causes troubles. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Florian pointed out in the comments: Use another renderer instead. For me, it was `xvimagesink` which caused the troubles.

Either

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin video-sink=ximagesink uri=...
```

or

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin video-sink=glimagesink uri=...
```

worked fine.